# Boiling point comparison between cyclohexane derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

I am trying to order these according to boiling point. I think that B is the highest because it has hydrogen bonding. I am not sure how to differentiate A and C though. They both have about the same molar mass. The only thing I can think is that C has a double bond. Does this double bond make the boiling point of C higher than A because it is stronger than a single bond? Or perhaps the double bond is shorter which decreases branching in C making the boiling point lower than A?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the double bond in C that is significant here, it's the oxygen. The carbon-oxygen bond is polar and will make C more "electrically sticky" with its neighbors compared to A. Since the $\ce{O-H}$ bond in B is even more polar than the ketone in C, its boiling point will be even higher. Read more about it on [this page](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Introductory_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_The_Basics_of_GOB_Chemistry_(Ball_et_al.)/14%3A_Organic_Compounds_of_Oxygen/14.10%3A_Properties_of_Aldehydes_and_Ketones).

(If you'd like to skip to the relevant section, on Google anyway, search "ketone vs alcohol boiling point".)